# Build Rule project(ODM) with the Build Command Line

Tags: command-line, executable-jar, ibm-odm

I am trying to find a way to build Ruleapp.jar from command line and going through this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.9.2/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/build_topics/tsk_buildcmd_line_build.html), and found a command.

```
java -jar Build_Command_Line_executable_archive -config configuration_file
```

Trying to figure out what "Build_Command_Line_executable_archive" is and from where I can get this jar to execute the above command

Answer (score 1):

The "Build_Command_Line_executable_archive" is a jar file that comes with ODM. You should be able to find it with the other ODM installation files. On my computer, this file is at:

```
C:\IBM\ODM89\buildcommand\rules-compiler\rules-compiler.jar
```

Note: In v8.9.1, there is a defect in the build command tool that causes the RuleApp archive that is generated to include the file "META-INF/archive.xml" that contains 'resuri' instead of 'reslib'. You have to manually edit this file in the RuleApp archive to fix it or write a script to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you, I guess the above command is for the ODM on-premises version. I  am using ODM -on  cloud. And rules-compier.jar is not available in my installation file.

Comment: That jar file should also be available as part of the Maven installation.

Comment: Is there any way to build this using Classic Rule Projects instead of Decision Services?